# Android Toast doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 with Android 8.0.

My Toast message (which was working) does not show up

```
Toast.makeText(this, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()` are not helping instead of this. Using this in an `activity`.

Comment: is it working in other devices?

Comment: Try to define activity name if u used like 

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: or fragment then define getActivity().

Comment: any chance you are calling this off your main thread?

Comment: thanks for you help...Defining the activity name is not working

Comment: It is working on other devices, is it possible to disable it on the device?

Comment: Are you trying to show it inside any condition? Check if Log print is working

Comment: @BvnBI everything works, just not the Toast for this Galaxy Note 8...

Comment: Can you post your complete activity code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your app `settings -> Notifications` and check if notifications are turned on. This action is possible in newer android versions

Even though a Toast is not a notification, it seems that `NotificationManagerService.java` will not show `Toast` if Notifications are disabled.

I'm posting a link with the issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36951147

Answer (score 1):

try with class name

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

here **ActivityName** is your activity name

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: I am firing it from different fragments - but it only does not work with the Galaxy Note 8, I think it's a device bug. Because it worked few days ago. The activity code is 4000 lines big. But thats my method, which is fired:

    //einfache Toastmessage anzeigen
    public void toastIt(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Answer (score -1):

wipe the data of emulator from AVD manager